# Merge methods of two objects with same properties into array for each property

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I'm trying to merge the methods of two objects into one such that an array of methods results for each property in the parent object:

```
obj1 = {"prop1":"method1","prop2":"method2"}
obj2 = {"prop1":"method3","prop2":"method4"}
```

Desired output:

```
obj1 = {"prop1":["method1","method3"],"prop2":["method2","method4"]}
```

I was thinking of using `$.extend(obj1,obj2)`, but this just replaces values and doesn't create an array. Is this task actually possible? If so, how is this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this helps:

```
var merge = function(/*...objs*/) {
  return [].reduce.call(arguments, function(acc, x) {
    Object.keys(x).forEach(function(k) {
      acc[k] = (acc[k]||[]).concat([x[k]])
    })
    return acc
  },{})
}

var obj1 = {prop1: "method1", prop2: "method2"}
var obj2 = {prop1: "method3", prop2: "method4"}

console.log(merge(obj1, obj2))
//^
// {prop1: ['method1', 'method3'],
//  prop2: ['method2', 'method4']}
```

Comment: What should be the code if instead of returning an _array_ as values, just return an string. I mean: `{prop1: 'method1, method3', prop2: 'method2, method4'}` ???

Answer (score 1):

As a comparison, you can use simple loops. The following is a little more to type, but to me it's much easier to understand and maintain. It also runs [*twice as fast*](http://jsperf.com/concat-ojbects) (or three times as fast in Safari) as elclanrs' answer.

```
function merge() {
  var result = {},
      obj;

  for (var i=0, iLen=arguments.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    obj = arguments[i];

    for (var p in obj) {

      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {

        if (!result.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
          result[p] = [];
        }
        result[p].push(obj[p]);
      } 
    }
  } 
  return result;
}
```

It's also safe for un–polyfilled ES3 hosts, so should run in every browser in use.

Comment: I like this one better, and was inspired by elchranrs answer to come up with something like this.  Thanks for suggesting!