# javascript merge array of objects, resulting object values in array

Tags: javascript, lodash

Would like to merge an array of objects resulting in an object of unique keys and array of values (duplication of values is ok). Solutions in vanilla JS or lodash preferred.

eg - from this:

```
[{ 
  a: 1, 
  b: 2 
}, { 
  a: 1, 
  c: 3 
}]
```

to this:

```
{ 
  a: [1, 1],
  b: [2],
  c: [3]
}
```

Comment: @eclanrs already has an answer to that  here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24336202/merge-methods-of-two-objects-with-same-properties-into-array-for-each-property

Comment: @Qiqo There input is individual objects. Here OP has array of objects. Still can be used as `merge(...array)`.

Comment: @Tushar. thanks I've updated my answer to reflect the change in order to accept array of objects.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`_.mergeWith()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#mergeWith) with the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) to combine the objects:

```js
const data = [{"a":1,"b":2},{"a":1,"c":3}];

const result = _.mergeWith({}, ...data, (v1 = [], v2) => [...v1, v2]);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If OP wanted to use external libraries, he/she would have done so. Stop obfuscating the web by loading in scripts for every little function.

Comment: Look at the tags attached to the question. They contain the word lodash.

Answer (score 1):

ES6 variant:

```js
const a = [{ 
  a: 1, 
  b: 2 
}, { 
  a: 1, 
  c: 3 
}]

const b = a.reduce((acc, cur) => Object.assign(acc, 
  ...Object.keys(cur).map(key => ({ [key]: (acc[key] || []).concat(cur[key]) })))
, {})

console.log(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

without loadash:

```
  var t = [{ 
  a: 1, 
  b: 2 
}, { 
  a: 1, 
  c: 3 
}];
var result = {};
debugger;
for(var i=0; i<t.length; i++){
    for(var j in t[i]){
        if(result.hasOwnProperty(j)){
            result[j].push(t[i][j]); 
        }else{
            result[j] = [t[i][j]];
        }
    }
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick search here in stack reveals that @elclanrs already wrote code for that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24336202/merge-methods-of-two-objects-with-same-properties-into-array-for-each-property) However based on the comments, it needs a little tweaking to accept an array of objects, so I added a bit of change to the original code itself.

so basically it boils to the function call:

```
var merge = function() {
  return [].reduce.call(arguments, function(acc, x) {
  for(i=0;i<x.length;i++){
    Object.keys(x[i]).forEach(function(k) {
      acc[k] = (acc[k]||[]).concat([x[i][k]])
    });
    }
    return acc
  },{})
}
}
```

Here's a snippet using the function call (with a bit of small change I put) in that post:

```js
var x = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 1,c: 3}]

var merge = function() {
  return [].reduce.call(arguments, function(acc, x) {
  for(i=0;i<x.length;i++){
    Object.keys(x[i]).forEach(function(k) {
      acc[k] = (acc[k]||[]).concat([x[i][k]])
    });
    }
    return acc
  },{})
}

y = merge(x);

alert(JSON.stringify(y));
```

Comment: Oh, you added an answer. Pass array as `merge(...x)`.

Comment: Thanks @Tushar, I've updated my answer to reflect the changes in order to accept array of objects

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`lodash#mergeWith`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#mergeWith) wrapped in a  [`lodash#spread`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#spread) to make `lodash#mergeWith` treat an array as a list of arguments. We use [`lodash#concat`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#concat) as a supporting function to concatenate an empty object (to avoid mutating the objects in the collection), the collection, and the customizer function that merges the entire collection. The customizer is composed using [`lodash#flow`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#flow), wherein its first argument is `lodash#concat` that only accepts an arity of 2 using [`lodash#ary`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#ary) and the second argument uses [`lodash#compact`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#compact) -- It removes all `undefined` values in an array.

```
var result = _.spread(_.mergeWith)(
  _.concat({}, data, _.flow(_.ary(_.concat, 2), _.compact))
);
```

```js
var data = [{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2
}, {
  "a": 1,
  "c": 3
}];

var result = _.spread(_.mergeWith)(
  _.concat({}, data, _.flow(_.ary(_.concat, 2), _.compact))
);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```